# Is this data structure recommendation/implementation request question on topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, recommendation-questions

I've come across this question: [Map alternative for primitive values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41726286/map-alternative-for-primitive-values)

It's clear and specific, asking for a Java `Map` implementation that will work with primitive types so as to avoid the overhead of corresponding boxed types.

However, it's attracting answers with all sorts of library recommendations.

Does this type of question fall under this close reason

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>   Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>   Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>   it.

or is it on topic?

Comment: This is one of those cases where the question isn't outright asking for library recommendations, but it might as well be. As for the guideline "Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.", the question does describe the problem, but I suspect many people will expect "what has been done so far" to contain code from and/or using an existing implementation, be it a custom implementation, or an existing library.

Comment: We are not trying to discourage answers from recommending a library to solve a specific programming problem. It looks to me like this person asked the question the smart way. They aren't asking you to find them a library or treating SO like a recommendation engine. They present an actual programming problem, and ask for a solution. I am not a Java expert, so I'll reserve posting an actual answer or casting a re-open vote of my own, but I honestly strain to see anything wrong with this question.

Comment: Meh. The question already hinges on a bad assumption: that switching from Object types to primitive types is going to make a significant dent on memory usage (it likely won't). And then rather than asking about solving the problem, it asks about implementing a particular technical solution instead. Not off-topic, just... unproductive. re-open vote cast.

Comment: Plain too broad. It is request list.